# Formatando Titulos na Table of Contents Rmarkdown (R)

Tags: html, css, r, rmarkdown

Esse é meu código em RMarkdown:

```
---
title: "Formatando Table of Contents"
author: "Laura"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  pagedown::html_paged:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 3

    self_contained: false
---

# Exercise 1{-}

<div style="width: 100%; height: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid black; text-align: center">
  <span style="font-size: 40px; background-color: white; padding: 0 10px;">
    Exercicio 1 <!--Padding is optional-->
  </span>
</div>
```

Nesse formato quando eu clico na table of contents em "Exercicio 1" ele me leva na página referente ao Título "Exercicio 1", obviamente.

Só que eu quero tirar o "Exercicio 1" não formatado e deixar apenas o formatado pelo código html/css. E mesmo assim continuar com o texto "Exercicio 1" na Table of Contents.

Eu consegui explicar?

Por exemplo, se eu faço isso repare que o Texto não formatado "Exercicio 1" desaparece (o que é muito bom!) e que fica é o Texto formatado. Porém eu "perco" esse texto na Table of contents

```
# {-}

<div style="width: 100%; height: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid black; text-align: center">
  <span style="font-size: 40px; background-color: white; padding: 0 10px;">
    Exercicio 1 <!--Padding is optional-->
  </span>
</div>
```

Não sei se a pergunta ficou clara peço desculpas mas não sei como resolver isso.

Eu desconfio que será necessário criar um arquivo .css para formatar o header 1 (h1) mas não sei como fazê-lo.

Alguma ajuda?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode adicionar `css` por code chuck (ou em um outro documento `style.css` se ele for muito grande) para mudar o style do documento. Lembrando que é mais fácil formatar a classe (no seu caso `h2`) que o formatar cada vez que usamos, como você estava fazendo.

````
---
title: "Formatando Table of Contents"
author: "Laura"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 3
---

```{css, echo=FALSE}
h2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:40px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

## Exercicio 1

Alguma coisa 1

## Exercise 2

Alguma coisa 2

<div style="width: 100%; height: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid black; text-align: center">
  <span style="font-size: 40px; background-color: white; padding: 0 10px;">
    Exercicio 3 <!--Padding is optional-->
  </span>
</div>

Alguma coisa 3
````

PS: não conheço muito de css, então tive que aumentar o `height` para `48` para que a linha não cruze as palavras